# Solving using separation of variable

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

First of all, I'm learning how to apply separation of variable method, and the first question I came across is this.

Solve $y'= 2x + y$ using separation of variables with substitution $u = 2x + y$.

Any kind souls here can help me by giving me steps and explanation for this question?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the question, why do we need a substitution to separate these variables?

Answer (score 1):

we have $u=2x+y$ then we get
$u'=2+y'=2+u$
thus we obtain
$u'=2+u$.

Answer (score 0):

$$u=2x+y$$

$$\frac{du}{dx}=2+\frac{dy}{dx}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2x+y\;\Longrightarrow\;\frac{du}{dx}-2=u$$

Therefore,

$$\frac{du}{u+2}=dx$$

Integrating,

$$y=Ae^x-2x-2$$